# Using jQuery Validate plugin to ensure at least one of three checkboxes is checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the jQuery Validate plugin, how can I make sure that at least one of three checkboxes has been checked? The best I can do so far is to make all three checkboxes required (which isn't what I want), and my code for getting this far is below.

I tried using [this example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) on the jQuery Validate demo page, but that requires the checkbox fields to each have the same name. I'm unable to do this, as these fields are pulled from a CMS and they each need the different names.

I want to keep this within jQuery validate as I've got lots of other fields being validated here (stripped out to keep this example clean) and it's the only way I can validate forms with my limited JS/jQuery knowledge. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form class="my_form" method="post" action="/" >

  <div><ul class="form_errors"></ul></div>

  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_1" name="my_checkbox_1[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 1</label>
  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_2" name="my_checkbox_2[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 2</label>
  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_3" name="my_checkbox_3[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 3</label>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Here's my JS:

```
$(".my_form").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
  wrapper: "li",
  rules: {
    'my_checkbox_1[]': { required: true },
    'my_checkbox_2[]': { required: true },
    'my_checkbox_3[]': { required: true }
  },
  messages: {
    'my_checkbox_1[]': "This field is required",
    'my_checkbox_2[]': "This field is required",
    'my_checkbox_3[]': "This field is required"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `require_from_group` rule included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js#L337).

```
rules: {
    'my_checkbox_1[]': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".my_checkbox_group"]
    }
}
```

- First parameter is the number of items to be required.
- Second parameter is the `class` assigned to all elements in your grouping.
- Also use [the `groups` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to consolidate the three messages into one.

New code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".my_form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
        wrapper: "li",
        groups: {
            names: "my_checkbox_1[] my_checkbox_2[] my_checkbox_3[]"
        },
        rules: {
            'my_checkbox_1[]': {
                require_from_group: [1, ".my_checkbox_group"]
            },
            'my_checkbox_2[]': {
                require_from_group: [1, ".my_checkbox_group"]
            },
            'my_checkbox_3[]': {
                require_from_group: [1, ".my_checkbox_group"]
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ya7Px/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the working demo, much appreciated. I did see the require_from_group rule but was put off trying it after seeing this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412 I'd failed to notice that additional-methods.js fixed it. I've implemented this answer with my full code and it appears to work great, thanks again.

Comment: I've been playing about more with this, and am finding that the validation isn't working on some of the required fields in the form. Here'a an amended demo to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/ya7Px/1/ Do you have any ideas on this at all?

Comment: @Stephen, I see nothing wrong with your code... you may have found a bug with the `require_from_group` method.  I suggest you post this [over at Github for the jQuery Validate plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues).  I validated your HTML and stripped out the superfluous code:  http://jsfiddle.net/ya7Px/3/

Comment: @Stephen, It looks like this same issue was reported to the developer 10 months ago:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412

Comment: That's the issue I linked to last week actually - I thought additional-methods.js worked around it. Looking at some other issues though, it looks like this require_from_group method is proving temperamental. A shame, as it's a pretty useful feature! I'll have to look into another method for now and hope they get to the bottom of it for good in the future. Thanks for checking the code though - could easily have minor an error on my behalf! :)

Comment: @Stephen, you simply misunderstood.  `additional-methods.js` is just where the method is contained.  Without this extra file, there is no `require_from_group` rule at all.  The last reply at Github was posted only 18 days ago, perhaps Jörn is closer to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

use the require_from_group method which is in additional-methods.js and takes a class name a first parameter and number required as the second

```
 <input class="productinfo" name="partnumber">
 <input class="productinfo" name="description">
```

...will validate unless at least one of them is filled.

```
partnumber:  {require_from_group: [1,".productinfo"]},
description: {require_from_group: [1,".productinfo"]}
```

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js#L337

Comment: Good answer, but the number is the _first_ parameter and the `class` is the _second_.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Looks like this is the way to go.