# jquery validation: password change and confirmation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I used jQuery validation in a form of member data modification. There are three fields in the form, i.e., original password (`passwordOrig`), new password (`password`), and password confirmation (`passwordSecond`). I'd like to ensure that the user enters either **all of them** or **none of them**. How do I do that with jQuery?

The following is what I have come up with:

```
$("#accountData").validate({
  rules: {
    passwordOrig: {checkPassword: true},
    password: {validChars: true, noSpace: true, minlength: 5},      
    passwordSecond: {equalTo: "#password"},
    ...
  }
  message: {
    ...
  }
```

In the above, `checkPassword`, `validChars`, and `noSpace` are added methods.

Comment: Please also include the HTML for your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure a minimum number of fields in a given set are either filled in or left blank - [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) has a method that addresses this requirement, called **skip_or_fill_minimum**

To use this rule you add a class to the inputs you are interested in

```
<input class="mygroup" name="fname" id="fname">
<input class="mygroup" name="sname" id="sname">
<input class="mygroup" name="other" id="other">
```

then specify the rule saying how many you need filled in, in your case all three, and the class you have used, in this case mygroup.

```
...
rules : {
 fname : {skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".mygroup"]}, 
 sname : {skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".mygroup"]},
 other : {skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".mygroup"]},
},
...
```

There is a good example of using the sister function require_from_group [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883356/678338)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include the [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) file and use an included rule called `skip_or_fill_minimum`.

Add a common `class` to the relevant `input` fields:

```
<form id="accountData">
    <input type="text" class="pw" name="passwordOrig" />
    <input type="text" class="pw" name="password" id="password" />
    <input type="text" class="pw" name="passwordSecond" />
    ....
</form>
```

The `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule requires two parameters, the number of fields in the grouping and the `class` name you created above, `skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#accountData').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            passwordOrig: {
                checkPassword: true,
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]
            },
            password: {
                validChars: true,
                noSpace: true,
                minlength: 5,
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]
            },
            passwordSecond: {
                equalTo: "#password",
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]
            }
        },
        groups: {
            justaname: "passwordOrig password passwordSecond"
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/DmTNW/**

I also used [the `groups:` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to group the three messages into one, but you could remove that if you want.  You may also want to replace your custom `noSpace` method with the one already included in the `additional-methods.js` file called `nowhitespace`, but again, this depends on your needs.